# Using data-ajax to call new page after reset session

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a multipage and work on mobile, I use PHP session to keep to consistence, I added a logout button on top and session should be cleared and reload the login page. Below is the content of page, login page is redirected after clicking the logout button but session id seem doesn't be cleared. I have already load the logout with data-ajax=false

HTML

```
<body class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-a">
    <section id="home" data-role="page">
        <header data-role="header">
            <h1>Summary</h1>
        </header>
        <article data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">
            <button href="#signin_section">Sign-in</button><br>
        </article> <!-- article content -->
    </section> <!-- section home -->

    <section id="signin_section" data-role="page">
        <header data-role="header">
            <h1>Summary</h1>
                <a href="/admin" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn-right ui-icon-power ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext">Logout</a>
        </header>
        <article data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">
                <div id="signin">
                    <form action="checklogin.php" name="form" id="form" method="post">
                        ... (content omitted) ...
                    </form>
                </div>
        </article> 
    </section> 
</body>
```

PHP script of Logout

```
<?php
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['login']);
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: http://jetsodev.aimedia.hk/admincheck");
?>
```

PHP script of Login

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
        if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
        ....
    }
?>
```

Comment: I tried it without the start_session() but not work, I turn on the Chrome console and always see the session id.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `session_unset` rather than `session_destroy`, since the latter “[does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php).”

Comment: Refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php, I use $_SESSION[] to check whether the session existed or not, so I use unset, I used both but session info was still kept in user browser.

Comment: The `_SESSION` object is intended to continue exist, but all the login info will be cleared. Isn’t that your intention?